# jQuery colorbox and alert

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am using this javascript for a ColorBox pop-up.

```
<script  src="$contextpath/js/jquery-1.7.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
```

and I am using the javascript below for an alert message.

```
<script src="jquery/js/jquery-1.9.0.js"></script>
<script src="jquery/js/jquery-ui-1.10.0.custom.min.js"></script>
```

In this case Colorbox is working properly but alert method is showing `"undefined method"`

```
$("#dialog").dialog( {
            modal : true,
            buttons : {
                Ok : function() {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        });
```

I have to use both things in same page. Can anybody provide solution for this?

Comment: find the html element with id="dialog" and see if its there?!

Comment: One .js for Alert and one for colorbox.

Comment: ya id="dialog"  is there